# JavaScript Json value append based up on equals conditions

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I am having two list of json data. I need to iterate each others and if the key and value matches with each other then i have to append a new key value pair into the first list. Please refer the following example for more details:

```
Example:
//array 1
var customers = [{
  CustomerName: 'Customer1',
},
{
  CustomerName: 'Customer2',
}];
// array 2
var locations= [{
  CustomerName: 'Customer1',
  latitude: 555555;
},
{
  CustomerName: 'Customer2',
  latitude: 666666;
},
{
  CustomerName: 'Customer3',
  latitude: 777777;
}];
// Iteration of the arrays
for(var i=0; i<customers.length; i++){
   for(var j=0;j<locations.length;j++) {
if(customers[i].CustomerName ==locations[j].CustomerName) {
// Here I want to add an element key value pair into existing array if condition get satisfied
customers[i].push(locations[j].lat);
alert(customers[i].lat);
}
}
}
```

Comment: If I undesrtand your question: customers.push({key: value});

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
customers[i].yourKey = yourValue;
```

as `customer[i]` will return your customer object, just treat it like an object. JavaScript is that nice to its users.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
customers = customers.map(function(val){
  var matchingLocation = locations.filter(function(loc){
    return loc.CustomerName = val.CustomerName;
  });
  val.lat = matchingLocation[0].latitude;
  return val;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your second array and compare each object with each object of your first array :

```
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < customers.length; j++){
        if(locations[i].CustomerName == customers[j].CustomerName){
          customers[j].latitude = locations[i].latitude
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/opppo7ep/2/

Answer (score 0):

This proposal works with two [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loops and creates first an object with the wanted references and in the second loop applies the wanted property to the `customer` array.

```js
var customers = [{ CustomerName: 'Customer1', }, { CustomerName: 'Customer2', }],
    locations = [{ CustomerName: 'Customer1', latitude: 555555 }, { CustomerName: 'Customer2', latitude: 666666 }, { CustomerName: 'Customer3', latitude: 777777 }],
    object = Object.create(null);

locations.forEach(function (a) {
    object[a.CustomerName] = a;
});

customers.forEach(function (a) {
    if (object[a.CustomerName]) {
        a.latitude = object[a.CustomerName].latitude;
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(customers, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects in your array (consumers, locations) contains Object not an array elements. push command is specifically for arrays but you can simply change you code to update property of your objects in array:

```
customers[i]["latitude"] = locations[j].latitude;
```

Live example:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z460wvgy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that there are some errors in your code.

First you have to remove ';' from locations (array 2) where you have name property of latitude, so your code must be :

```
var locations = [{
    CustomerName: 'c1',
    latitude: 555555
},
{
    CustomerName: 'c2',
    latitude: 666666
},
{
    CustomerName: 'c2',
    latitude: 666666
}];
```

And customers and locations are array of Objects, so every item ( locations[j], or customers[i]) in each array is an Object, though you can't write push to an Object, because there is no push function for an Object.

So to add new properties to existing JavaScript Objects you can use the dot notation like :
`customers[i].latitude = locations[j].latitude`

or you can use Bracket Notation:

`customers[i]['latitude] = locations[j].latitude`.

To debug your code you can use the Chrome developers tools by clicking on (CTRL + SHIFT + i) or by F-12 on your keyboard.

You can use

`console.log(customers[i]);` 
to see all the changes to your array of Objects, but it's easier to use :

`debugger;`

And here is my solution code to your problem : https://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_daka/sfhqLqan/

I noticed that you wrote in your question that your array of Objects is a list of JSON data, and this is not true.

Because valid JavaScript code is not necessary a valid JSON - JavaScript Object Notation.

But JSON is an actually a valid JavaScript Object.

And the difference between JavaScript Object and JSON in that the JSON name value pair must be quoted.

I explained everything about JSON for you here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_daka/fn4024yx/47/

I hope my solution helped you. Thanks and good luck:)